# Как создавать коллекции в Jekyll

Tags: коллекции, jekyll

Делаю сайт на **GitHub Pages**. У меня есть заготовки страниц типа "**About.md**", "**Projects.md**" и т.п. Хранятся они в папке **pages**.

Я хочу вывести их в `header` в виде кнопок меню. Перечитал кучу статей, но так и не понял, как мне их организовать в коллекцию.

Объясните пожалуйста как для тупого: что нужно добавить в **_config.yml**, какие файлы и с чем необходимо ещё создать и что в какую папку положить.

Comment: Я могу конечно просто захардкодить эти пункты меню, но в дальнейшем коллекции мне ещё пригодятся, поэтому хотелось бы научится их применять.

Comment: Вот пример сайдбара: https://github.com/poole/hyde/blob/master/_includes/sidebar.html . Прямо в шаблоне прописан вывод страниц циклом, выбираются страницы, где `layout == "page"`

Comment: Спасибо! Этот вариант сейчас мне подходит, но кроме этого я хотел бы создавать коллекции ссылок к примеру на другие репозитории и выводить их, поэтому вопрос остаётся открытым.

Comment: А официальную документацию jekyll смотрели? Вот доки по коллекциям: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/ . Для списка репозиториев возможно будет удобнее хранить такой список в файле данных (yaml, json, csv): https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/

Comment: Смотрел, но так как с английским у меня печально, мог чего-то упустить. Насчёт списка да, скорее всего буду использовать файл типа projects.yaml. А а страницы для буду искать ещё и по тегу "main-menu", на случай если ещё буду страницы добавлять.

Comment: Даже если что-то не понятно в документации, можно по-быстрому отдельный репозиторий github pages создать, на нем потренироваться. Я обычно так делаю, потому что jekyll досконально не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Долго пытался создать коллекцию на локальном сервере, перепробовал все варианты, думал я чего-то неправильно делаю...

Оказалось нужно было всё пересобрать командой `bundle exec jekyll serve`